# Change contents of the a file on server reboot

Tags: shell, unix

I have a requirement to edit the first line a file on the server reboot. For example, We have a file hostname.cfg on ServerA. The hostname of the ServerA is ServerA. Now if the move the file on ServerB (Hostname ServerB) the file hostname.cfg will contain ServerB. How to do this ? I have sample code attached.

File on ServerA - hostname.cfg is having "ServerA"

Upon moving to ServerB - should be having "ServerB"

I am trying with

## !/bin/ksh

if [[ $HOSTNAME == tstcogdb1 ]];
then
print "Node1"
else
print "Node2"
fi

It is printing "Node2"

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work better at least:

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [[ $HOSTNAME == tstcogdb1 ]]; then print "Node1"; else print "Node2"; fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [[ $HOSTNAME == tstcogdb1 ]]
  then print "Node1"
  else print "Node2"
fi
```

Though I can't really imagine why one would want to do what you are asking...